# HtmlAgilityPack Wildcard Search in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, dom, xpath, html-agility-pack

How could I shorten the following?

`$contactsBlock` is an HTMLAgilityPack node, XPath: `/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]`

`$contactsBlock.SelectSingleNode(".//table").SelectSingleNode(".//table")`

Results in desired XPath: `/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]`

The second table is nested in the first, and I'd like to shorten the above `SelectSingleNode` twice to something like this

`$contactsBlock.SelectSingleNode(".//table/*/table")` and skip the in-between.

Is there a way to wild-card like this?

Comment: Try `.//table//table`. That should match all tables nested within other tables.

Comment: Yes. I will make this the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath expression `.//table//table` should match all tables nested within other tables under the current node. Double forward slashes match arbitrary length paths.

`.//table/*/table` is unlikely to give you a match, because the asterisk wildcard matches one node (i.e. one level of hierarchy), so the nested table would have to be a grandchild node of the first table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <table>...</table>   <!-- nested table would have to go here -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

which would be quite unusual. Doesn't match the structure suggested by the XPath expression from your question, too.